# Cannot match a regular expression

Tags: regex

I am trying to match the following two words, but for some reason, my regexp doesn't work

Here is what I'm trying to match: `OCXXXXXX GXXXXXXX`

X being any number or letter

Here is my regexp

```
OC[a-zA-Z0-9]+\sG[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

if I remove the dollar sign, it owrks, but I want the regexp to match exactly those two words and fail if there ar emote than those two words. Because of that, I want to use the $. Any ideas why this does not work?

Comment: Do you have a line break at the end of the string? If so, you'd want to enable the multiline option.

Answer (score 2):

May be you have a space at the end, try this:

```
OC[a-zA-Z0-9]+\sG[a-zA-Z0-9]+\b
```

or

```
OC[a-zA-Z0-9]+\sG[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s*
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats weird, it is now working. I was using this website:

http://www.regexr.com/

I ended up uding

```
^OC[a-zA-Z0-9]+\sG[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

After I refreshed the website, it started working. Sorry about this post.
Thanks anyway M42

Answer (score 1):

`^\s*OC[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s+G[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s*$` should work.

Its anchored at beginning and end of string `^$` and allows for optional
whitespace at beginning or end and required whitespace between words.
The quantifiers on the whitespace are open ended.